# Php is stripping one letter "g" from my rtrim function but not other chars

Tags: php, url, youtube

I'm trying to trim some youtube URLs that I am reading in from a playlist.  The first 3 work fine and all their URLs either end in caps or numbers but this one that ends in a lower case g is getting trimmed one character shorter than the rest.

```
    for ($z=0; $z <= 3; $z++)
  {
   $ythref2 = rtrim($tubeArray["feed"]["entry"][$z]["link"][0]["href"], '&feature=youtube_gdata');
```

The URL is `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuE88oVCVjg&feature=youtube_gdata` .. and it should get trimmed down to .. `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuE88oVCVjg` but instead it is coming out as `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuE88oVCVj`.

I think it may be the ampersand symbol but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's the `g` in the second argument. `rtrim()` does not remove a string from the end, it removes any characters given in the second argument. Use `preg_replace()` or `substr()` instead.

Comment: Perfect, used substr.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to [rtrim](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php) is a *list of characters to remove*, not a string to remove.

You might want to use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php), or use [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) to get arrays of the components of the URL and the components of the query string, like "v".

Untested example code:

```
$youtube_url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CuE88oVCVjg&feature=youtube_gdata';
$url_bits = parse_url($youtube_url);
$query_string = array();
parse_str($url_bits['query'], $query_string);
$video_identifier = $query_string['v']; // "CuE88oVCVjg"
$rebuilt_url = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=' . $video_identifier;
```